# Hahn Banach Theorem, Linear Functionals, Sublinear Functional

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

Let $f : X \rightarrow R$ be a mapping on a real vector space X.

Suppose that $f$ is sublinear but not linear, i.e., there exists $x^{*} \in X$ such that $f(−x^{*}) \neq -f(x^{*})$. Use the Hahn-Banach Theorem to show that there
exist two different linear forms $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ on X such that $L_{1}(x) \leq f(x)$ and
$L_{2}(x) \leq f(x)$ for all x ∈ X.

I am trying to prove this statement. So, far what I have done is that I have defined 2 subspaces on X.

$ W=\{x^{*}| f(−x^{*}) \neq -f(x^{*})\} $  &  $V$ be the trivial {0} subspace.

Let $l_{1}$ be a linear mapping on $W$ and $l_{2}$ be a linear mapping on V. Then by Hahn Banach Theorem there exists linear map, $L_{1}$ & $L_{2}$ on X such that $L_{1}(x) \leq f(x)$ and
$L_{2}(x) \leq f(x)$ for all x ∈ X.

But I don't understand how to show $L_{1}$ & $L_{2}$ are different/distinct maps. Any help will be highly appreciated and thanks in Advance. Please also feel free to comment on what I have done so far.

Comment: $V$ is not a subspace and does not contain $0$

Comment: Why are the linear functionals $l_1$ and $l_2$ guaranteed to be dominated by $f(x)$ on the subspaces you've defined? This is an existence proof. You need to *write down* explicitly the two functionals.